# When did my British Citizenship expire?

Tags: citizenship, australia, uk-citizens

I was born in the United Kindom in 1997, both of my parents were British, but in 2004 we moved to Australia where we have lived ever since. I became an Australian Citizen in 2008

I am now applying for a UK Citizenship, and the form is asking me the date range I was a British Citizen for. I know the start date was the day I was born, but when did my British Citizenship "expire"?

Comment: Do you mean you are applying for a British passport? Based on your question it appears you are *already* a British citizen https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizenship/born-in-the-uk-between-1-january-1983-and-1-october-2000

Comment: Oh, looks like I am a still a British Citizen I guess :P

Comment: If so, you can just apply for a passport https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-adult-passport

Answer (score 8):

British citizenship does not expire. If you did not apply to renounce your British citizenship (and was approved), you are still a British citizen. You cannot "apply for" British citizenship as you already have it. As a British citizen, you can simply apply for a British passport at any time.